# Can you identify these 1x2 and 2x2 bricks with grooves?

Tags: part-identification

As far as I understand, these are modified with groove bricks. However, search for 'groove' on BrickLink gives only left one. Which are the other two? Which other parts have similar vertical groove and do not have 'groove' word in the name?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Actually found via Google pictures. On bricklink need to use 'grooves' in search, partial matches do not work there.

Comment: They do if you put an asterisk (\*) at the end of the search word, such as "groove\*". I am not sure about other placeholder symbols.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the listings from Bricklink.com (left to right).

**Brick, Modified 1 x 2 with Groove**
https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4216#T=C

**Brick, Modified 2 x 2 with Grooves and Axle Hole**
https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=90258#T=C

I'm not sure about the last one. Maybe:

**Brick, Modified 2 x 2 x 6 with Groove**
https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6056#T=C